# Can't import .sql files in phpmyadmin

Tags: lamp, phpmyadmin, sql

I had exported databases from wamp and tried importing the same from phpmyadmin but it displays an error saying you probably tried uploading a file that was too large! Why? How should I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had not made the database and was including the .sql files without creating the relevant databases. Now I created the databases and the .sql files are imported easily, without any problem! So there was no problem with the size of .sql files to start with. Its was my silly mistake to be importing the .sql files without creating the databases. But its my first time working with LAMP and Ubuntu so its considerable. That's it! Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

You should check the `upload_max_filesize` value in your "php.ini" file:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

Comment: Its 2M! Now what about it? What should I do next? That doesn't solve my problem does it? @Contao

Comment: 2M stands for 2 MegaByte

please check the size of your file and increase the `upload_max_filesize` value